# JQUERY - how to make text display as its containing div box is sliding left to right?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So i have a containing div, with a heading "about me", and echoed text inside the containing div. when the div slides from left to right, only upon completion of the slide, does all the text magically appear at once. how do i get the text to appear with the slide, rather than magically at once after it. ie. the sliding div reveals the text as it slides, not finishes, and then reveals it.

here is my css:

```
/*ABOUT CARD SLIDE RIGHT*/
.profile-about { /* contains profile card and about card */
float: left;
}

.u-about50 {
display: none;
position: relative;
top: 113px;
right: 79px;
width: 600px;
height: 220px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 11;
}

.ubout {
margin: 0px;
position: relative;
bottom: 200px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;

}

.a-btn {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 left: 500px;
 top: 270px;
 z-index: 12;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #333333;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #333333;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-style: solid;
 box-shadow: none;
 font-family: Lucidatypewriter, monospace;
 color: white;
}
```

here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {


$('.dropbtn').on('mouseenter', () => {
$('.dropdown-content').slideDown('slow');
});

$('.dropdown-content').on('mouseleave', () => {
$('.dropdown-content').slideUp('slow');
});

$('.a-btn').on('click', () => {
  $('.u-about50').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'},1000);

});


});
```

here is my html:

```
 <section>
 <div>
    <div class="profile-about">
    <div class="u-profile-card">
        <h3>Guide:</h3>
        <div>
          <h2><?php echo ucfirst($first);?> <?php echo $last; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img-txt">
        <div class="image-cropper">
        <img class="u-image" src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="no 
   image found">
        </div>
        <div class="u-info">
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_city); ?>, <?php echo ucfirst($u_region); ? 
  >, <?php echo ucfirst($u_country); ?></h2>
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($u_rating); ?> Stars</h2>
        <h2 class="u-email"><?php echo ucfirst($email); ?></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="a-btn">About</button>
    <div class="u-about50">
        <div class="ubout">
          <h1>About me</h1>
          <p><?php echo ucfirst($about); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's some larger flow/positioning at play, which led to the specific CSS you currently have applied, but the problem in its current form (based on the snippets provided at least) is the use of relative positioning for both the `.u-about50` element and its child `.ubout`.

By removing the `position:relative` rule on the `.ubout` element, the desired result is achieved with the text being present as the element slides in & out of view.

CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGbqax

Again, to achieve the result, I simply removed the `position:relative` from the `.ubout` class rules:

```
.ubout {
margin: 0px;
bottom: 200px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: lightgray; /* added for illustration */
}
```